# How to paginate a foreach in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, pagination

The only thing I could do is limit the foreach to 8, but really, what I want is to make it paginated.

The code does show some posts in the "posts" folder, but what I want, as I said, is paginated.

```
<?php
$ruta = "posts"; // Indicar ruta
$directorio = opendir($ruta);
$get = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) {
    if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess' && substr($archivo, -4) == '.php') {
        $entradas[$archivo] = filemtime($ruta."/".$archivo);
} //Fin de la Condicion if
} //Fin del While
arsort ($entradas);
closedir($directorio);

function limit($iterable, $limit) {
    foreach ($iterable as $key => $value) {
        if (!$limit--) break;
        yield $key => $value;
    }
}

// $array_slice_feed = array_slice($entradas, (count($entradas) - 5));

foreach (limit($entradas, 8) as $archivo => $timestamp) {
        //Extraemos el Contenido de los Post para despues Mostrarlo
        $post = $archivo;
        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $img = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $imagen = $img->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $title = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('div');
        $titulo = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $des = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('div');
        $descripcion = $des->item(1)->nodeValue;

        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $author = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('div');
        $autor = $author->item(2)->nodeValue;

        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $fecha1 = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('div');
        $fecha2 = $fecha1->item(3)->nodeValue;

        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $DataDia = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('div');
        $Data_Dia = $DataDia->item(3)->getAttribute("data-day");

        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $DataMes = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('div');
        $Data_Month = $DataMes->item(3)->getAttribute("data-mes");

        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $hora1 = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('div');
        $hora2 = $hora1->item(4)->nodeValue;

        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $desW = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('div');
        $descripcionWeb = $desW->item(5)->nodeValue;

        $desde = 0;
        $hasta = 56;

        if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
            $cadena_buscada = $_GET['cat'];
        } elseif (isset($_GET['buscar'])) {
            $cadena_buscada = $_GET['buscar'];
        }else{
            $cadena_buscada = NULL;
        }

        if (preg_match("/$cadena_buscada/i", "$descripcion")) {
            echo "
            <article>
                <div class='thumb'>
                    <img src='$imagen' />
                </div>

                <a href='$ruta/$archivo'>
                    $titulo
                    <span><i class='icon-folder2'></i> $descripcion</span>
                </a>
            </article>
            ";
        } else if (preg_match("/$cadena_buscada/i", "$titulo")) {
            echo "
            <article>
                <div class='thumb'>
                    <img src='$imagen' />
                </div>

                <a href='$ruta/$archivo'>
                    $titulo
                    <span><i class='icon-folder2'></i> $titulo</span>
                </a>
            </article>
            ";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're injecting tainted content into `preg_match` - I think that might be susceptible to `eval` injection.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how this works, and what problem you are having? It looks like you are doing a lot of expensive file operations in your `foreach` loop, do you need to read this XML doc into a database, so you can paginate using SQL?

Comment: For starters, I do not use database.
My project is a blog, which can be created posts. These posts are stored in the folder posts.

The PHP code that just passed, what it does is go that folder, and search each file certain elements of the DOM.

As you can see here, shows me the posts, thanks to this code:
https://i.gyazo.com/5d8d8ae3c429c497a8dea529b88b0641.png

In the top of the page, I have a posts.php include the file containing this code

Answer (score 1):

I can't test without data, if you want pagination you must specify starting point too, not just limit per page. Also I don't know why are you using yield, maybe it will be more readable if you use just array_slice for that logic, I also removed part of repeating code...

```
    <?php
    $ruta = "posts"; // Indicar ruta
    $directorio = opendir($ruta);
    $get = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) {
        if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess' && substr($archivo, -4) == '.php') {
            $entradas[$archivo] = filemtime($ruta."/".$archivo);
        } //Fin de la Condicion if
    } //Fin del While
    arsort ($entradas);
    closedir($directorio);

    function limit($iterable, $from, $per_page = 8)
    {
        $i    = 0;
        $page = 0;
        foreach ($iterable as $key => $value) {
            ++$page;
            if ($from <= $page && $i < $per_page) {
                ++$i;
                yield $key => $value;
            }
        }
    }

    # pagination start
    $per_page     = 8;
    $num_of_pages = count($entradas);
    $from         = (int)(isset($_GET['from']) ? $_GET['from'] : 0);
    unset($_GET['from']);
    $query_string = http_build_query($_GET);

    for ($i = 0; $i <= floor(($num_of_pages-1) / $per_page); $i++) {
        echo " <a href='?from=$i&$query_string'> " . ($i + 1) . " </a> | ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    # pagination end

    foreach (limit($entradas, $from * $per_page, $per_page) as $archivo => $timestamp) {
        //Extraemos el Contenido de los Post para despues Mostrarlo
        $post = $archivo;
        $get->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("posts/$post"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $contenedor = $get->getElementById('post');
        $img        = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $imagen     = $img->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

        $title          = $contenedor->getElementsByTagName('div');
        $titulo         = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $descripcion    = $title->item(1)->nodeValue;
        $autor          = $title->item(2)->nodeValue;
        $fecha2         = $title->item(3)->nodeValue;
        $Data_Dia       = $title->item(3)->getAttribute("data-day");
        $Data_Month     = $title->item(3)->getAttribute("data-mes");
        $hora2          = $title->item(4)->nodeValue;
        $descripcionWeb = $title->item(5)->nodeValue;

        $desde = 0;
        $hasta = 56;

        if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
            $cadena_buscada = $_GET['cat'];
        } elseif (isset($_GET['buscar'])) {
            $cadena_buscada = $_GET['buscar'];
        } else {
            $cadena_buscada = null;
        }

        if (preg_match("/$cadena_buscada/i", "$descripcion")) {
            echo "
                <article>
                    <div class='thumb'>
                        <img src='$imagen' />
                    </div>

                    <a href='$ruta/$archivo'>
                        $titulo
                        <span><i class='icon-folder2'></i> $descripcion</span>
                    </a>
                </article>
                ";
        } else if (preg_match("/$cadena_buscada/i", "$titulo")) {
            echo "
                <article>
                    <div class='thumb'>
                        <img src='$imagen' />
                    </div>

                    <a href='$ruta/$archivo'>
                        $titulo
                        <span><i class='icon-folder2'></i> $titulo</span>
                    </a>
                </article>
                ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, seriously! I work, but I have a little problem.

Look, I have 10 items on the top of the page, but only shows me 8!
https://gyazo.com/b748fef79ba0d82cc8f3498c290833b7

Comment: I eddited part with pagination, try to change part between "pagination start" and "pagination end", I think it works now, there was error in calculating numbers of pages.